# DSE + solr back pressure issue for index work pool

Tags: solr, solr4, datastax-enterprise, datastax

restarting a node B in a three node cluster always ends in the following warn message on the node B:

> Back pressure is active for Index work pool with total work queue size 764 and average processing time 9242

the queue size is constantly increasing.
I'm running DSE 4.5 SOLR on a ubuntu 12.04 machine with 20 GB RAM, 4 Cores per server. Monitoring the Systemresources seems to be "normal" , 12 GB RAM usage, very low CPU usage.

opscenter is showing me for this node:

a heap usage of 1,5 GB, a very low load (0.32), a compaction task of a keyspace that is at 100% for several hours now.

On node A a nodetool -pr   always show the message:

> INFO [HintedHandoff:2] 2015-01-05 17:24:19,570 HintedHandOffManager.java (line 466) Timed out replaying hints to /10.0.106.200; aborting (0 delivered)

where 10.0.106.200 is node B

Any idea what this Warning could cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backpressure warning is just an indication of overloading, as the indexing process isn't able to keep up with the insertion rate according to your configured threshold; generally, it is not a serious issue unless it happens for a prolonged period of time, in which case you might want to scale either horizontally or vertically, or increase the backpressure threshold if you already have powerful machines.

As for the other problems, they look a bit more serious, but it's difficult to diagnose with so little information.

Comment: thanks, we've just did a upgrade from 4.5.1 to 4.6 and all problems are solved. the issue in 4.5.1 were that on one node the compaction get stuck and i wasn't able to stop/clear them. we didn't change anything on the nodes configurably, but added two new tables. there were some issues in replication solrconfig.xml to the other nodes etc. it started with this.